# Why is the upper part of a Leyden jar terminated with a small sphere?

Tags: capacitance, history

I often see pictures of Leyden jars that have a small ball attached to the end of the upper connector, was it just a question of aesthetic ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a sphere means that the jar can retain the maximum amount of charge, as opposed to a shape with sharp edges which will discharge through [corona discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge).

Comment: So if I correctly understood, this spherical symmetry provides an optimal transfer of charge when we're charging the jar, does it ?

Comment: I effect just the opposite. To simplify: High voltage on sharp point starts to 'spray' the electrons out. By having a round end the bottle does not self-discharge so quickly. If you look at high voltage systems (e.g. Tesla coils) you will notice that the high voltage end is connected to all round shapes. Except where you **want** the disscharge. There you find a 'sharp' object. (Again look at Tesla coils)